# i cannot upload images greater than 2,5 M

Tags: php, javascript, uploadify

i am using uploadify 2.1.4 in order to upload big files , now, the problem is that i can't upload images greater than 2M apparently!

My settings on the php.ini are all set to large numbers so they should work!
my settings for the script are:

```
'uploader': 'uploadifyit/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'uploadifyit/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadifyit/cancel.png',
        'folder': 'images',
        'auto': false, // use for auto upload
        'multi': true,
        'queueSizeLimit': 100,
                 'sizeLimit': 20971520,

post_max_size = 30M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
max_execution_time = 600     
max_input_time = 600    
memory_limit = 64M
```

Can you please indicate to me what am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart your server after changing the PHP settings?

Comment: Could you share the relevant .ini settings just in case? And are you sure that those values are in effect?

Comment: I have updated the question with my values in the php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot increase the limits yourself then your host is likely preventing it. Submit a ticket to your hosting provider requesting a limit increase, they will probably say no assuming you are on a reseller or shared hosting platform.

To modify PHP settings you will likely need a VPS as a minimum since most shared and reseller (shared) will share the PHP.ini between users.